# Obrigar que toda instância tenha 2 atributos

Tags: java

Olá,
Eu tenho uma classe Funcionario com os atributos nome, codigo e salario (todos private), e uma classe Gerente - que extende Funcionario - com o atributo quantidadeFuncionarios, também private.

Como posso obrigar que toda instância de Gerente tenha quantidadeFuncionarios e nome, sendo que nome é um atributo da classe pai?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas se Gerente é filho de Funcionário, `nome` também será um atributo privado de Gerente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas crie **um único construtor** na classe **Gerente** com os 2 parâmetros, dessa forma não será possível instanciar Gerente sem parâmetros.

Exemplo:

### Funcionario.java

```
public class Funcionario {
    private String nome;

    public Funcionario(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }    

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

### Gerente.java

```
public class Gerente extends Funcionario {
    private int quantidadeFuncionarios;

    public Gerente(String nome, int quantidadeFuncionarios) {
        super(nome); // construtor do funcionário
        if(nome == null || nome.isEmpty()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nome não pode ser vazio");
        }
        if(quantidadeFuncionarios < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantidade funcionarios não opde ser inferior a zero");
        }
        this.quantidadeFuncionarios = quantidadeFuncionarios;
    }

    public int getQuantidadeFuncionarios() {
        return quantidadeFuncionarios;
    }

    public void setQuantidadeFuncionarios(int quantidadeFuncionarios) {
        this.quantidadeFuncionarios = quantidadeFuncionarios;
    }
}
```

*Incrementei o código acima com as validações segeridas pelo [Filipe Gonzaga Miranda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21766/filipe-gonzaga-miranda)*.

### Utilizando

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Gerente gerente = new Gerente("Ana", 3); /* sem parâmetros da erro */
    System.out.println(gerente.getNome() + " - " + gerente.getQuantidadeFuncionarios());
}
```

### Saída

> Ana - 3

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigada pela ajuda :)
Fiz exatamente como me mostrou, mas na primeira linha do construtor - this.setNome(nome); - o NetBeans exibe o erro "cannot find symbol".

Comment: @Ana você criou os `get/set` do atributo `nome` na classe funcionário e está herdando corretamente?

Comment: @Ana Atualizei minha resposta com o código do Funcionário, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Encontrei o erro aqui, valeu!

Comment: De verdade não entendo esse pessoal que eleva a competitividade acima da informação, apesar da minha resposta não ser a melhor ela atendeu a necessidade da autora da pergunta. Qual necessidade de negativar só pra outra resposta se destacar mais sendo que copiou o código da minha resposta incluindo o comentário.

Comment: Conselho: o nome do funcionário devia ser imutável, e injectado pelo construtor, sem setter.

Comment: @dcastro Atualizei o código e como ela já marcou como a correta eu adicionei as validações que o Filipe sugeriu.

Answer (score 4):

@Ana, além de usar o construtor, valide também os métodos,assim você cria invariantes para sua classe e impões regras para os estados que sua classe pode estar. Em outras palavras, não basta criar um gerente com um numero de **quantidadeFuncionarios**
É importante garantir que essa quantidaed é `>= 0` (maior ou igual a zero) ou mesmo que seja maior que zero.

Outra importante validação no momento da criação, é você ter certeza que os usuários da sua classe não vão definir um nome `nulo` ou vazio `""`

```
public Gerente(String nome, int quantidadeFuncionarios) {
        if(nome == null || nome.isEmpty()){
            throw new IllegaArgumentException("Nome não pode ser vazio");
        }
        if(quantidadeFuncionarios < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantidade funcionarios não opde ser inferior a zero");
        }
        this.setNome(nome); // herdando do funcionário
        this.quantidadeFuncionarios = quantidadeFuncionarios;
    }
```

A melhor maneira de realmente forçar que seus objetos estejam em um estado válido é esta.

Chque a documentação esta excessão:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

**Considere fazer seus objetos imutáveis.**

Outra maneira de garantir as invariantes de sua classe é redesenha-la para ser imutável.

Existem alguns trade offs a serem considerados, cheque este tutorial:
http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/o-modelo-da-bolsa-de-valores-datas-e-objetos-imutaveis/